# Ctrl + Space in java gui

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

how can I upload another frame (when i am running on my frame) by press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>?

I mean , I am on the main frame, and I want that by push <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> in the keyboard, another frame will coming up.

i've tried some things but I just found the option with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + 'key' (mnemonic) but Iwant <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

---

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) { 
        if(ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL + KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ 
            System.out.println("Halleluya!"); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

this is my code, but it doesnt work. But if i do just like this:

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) { 
        if(ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ 
            System.out.println("Halleluya!");
```

so i get "Halleuya" on the console. but i need just when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>...

Comment: What type of GUI? JavaFX? Swing? If Swing then look into using [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Please show pertinent [mcve] code and add the important details (such as GUI library) to make your question more answerable.

Comment: Also your question is a multi-parter -- how to respond to key press, how to launch a new window, and you should try to solve both problems separately, and then if stuck, ask your questions separately.

Comment: thanks for your comment.
'code'

this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
    
    if(ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL + KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
     System.out.println("Halleluya!");
    }
   }
  });
'code'

this is my code. it doesnt work. but if i do just like this:
'code'

this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
    
    if(ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
     System.out.println("Halleluya!");

'code'

so i get "Halleuya" on the console.
but i need just when ctrl + space...

Comment: Please don't post code in comments but rather in the bopdy of your question as code-formatted text. So we see that it is a Swing question. Then your answer is to use Key Bindings. Please read the [tutorial on Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), and in the future if stuck, please strive to ask a much more specific and informative question. Please have a look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).